# I am kinda confused here on using ternary

Tags: javascript

So I am just trying to calculate grade average here with this code. I am getting undefined I'm not sure why.

```
   const finalGrade = (num1,num2,num3) =>{
  let sum = num1 + num2 + num3;
  let grade = sum / 3;

  grade < 59 ? 'F': 
  grade < 69 ? 'D': 
  grade < 79 ? 'C': 
  grade < 89 ? 'B': 
  grade < 100 ?'A': console.log('Error!');


}
```

Comment: missing `return` statement?!!!

Comment: Yes, I was. I am still new to this wasn't sure what I was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
  const finalGrade = (num1,num2,num3) =>{
  let sum = num1 + num2 + num3;
  let grade = sum / 3;

  return grade < 59 ? 'F': 
         grade < 69 ? 'D': 
         grade < 79 ? 'C': 
         grade < 89 ? 'B': 
         grade < 100 ?'A': console.log('Error!');
}
```